# Test monitor by looking at it using a camera (to check for waves)

Tags: display

I've been told that you can use a camera to look on the monitor and see whether there are some waves on the screen; that would be a way to check if the monitor is good or not. ***Is this true?***
I'm looking at my monitor with a mobile phone camera and I see some vertical waves going (if there is a white background)

Comment: +1, but as mentioned in two very good answers it's not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is an artifact of the screen rendering.

Your monitor draws the screen *X* times per second and your camera draws it *Y* times per second. If they where perfectly in sync the interference would disappear.

Answer (score 3):

This vertical waves don't tell anything about goodness of monitor...

You can see vertical waves depending on screen refresh rate in Hertz (Hz).
LCD standard rate is 60 Hz... You can try camera on 100 Hz and 200 Hz displays (3D image compatible) and you won't find any waves on it.

Monitors main tech specs is view angle, response time (black to white, white to black), resolution and input interfaces. If you want play 3D games, you must buy 100Hz or 200Hz monitor. For standard games the 60Hz is quite enough.

Comment: I'm more worried about my eyes getting tired, not about playing games, I'm using the monitor for work (programming)